# Azure Blob Rehydration from Archive

Tags: azure, archive

When an archive blob storage is hydrated to either hot or cool tier, it becomes live again is my understanding for read operation or altering?

Does the archive blob no longer exist at this point after the 15hours hydrate period?

What I'm trying to ascertain; is the blob storage moved from archive tier to hot/cool or does the archive persist after the hydrate.
The concern being if long term data is is hydrated and altered?

Any advice on the above would be much appreciated as I cant seem to find an answer for this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Upon completion, the Archive status property is removed, and the Access Tier blob property reflects the new Hot or Cool tier.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers#archive-access-tier

Comment: Thank you, I read that article also. So if it returns to a writable tier (hot/cool) data integrity could be altered and the original archive is no longer?

Comment: The access tier doesn't make it immutable.  Please see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutable-storage